# Memory leak in linked list implementation C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I don't know if there is another thread with my problem, but if there is, I could not find it.

the thing in question is the freeing of the now unused cell/node of the linked list.
I get with the program in the current state the exact amount of leakage, that I predict, but the 2 'free()' that I use seemingly overkill and the IDE already warns me about access on freed memory.
(I already run it and the IDE was right)
So, how do I rewrite my code to actually just free the 1 cell it should?

my nodes:

```
typedef struct node {
    char val[2] ; //arrays (in this project of size 2)
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

```
// removes the item at the given position from the list (starting counting from 0)
// memory leakage but idk how to free
node_t* remove_from_list(node_t *head, int index){
    node_t *prev = make_list();
    printf("prev:");
    print_list(prev);
    node_t *target = head;
    printf("target:");
    print_list(target);
    // jumping to the location
    while (index > 0){
        *prev = *target;
        target = target->next;
        index--;
    }
    printf("after jump target:");
    print_list(target);
    printf("new prev:");
    print_list(prev);
    sleep(1);
    //checking if last slot in list
    if (is_list_empty(*target) == 2){ //true
        printf("last in chain");
        sleep(1);
        if (is_list_empty(*prev) == 0){ //list of only 1 elem special case
            printf("and (0)\n");
            sleep(1);
            free(prev);
            free(target);
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
            prev->next = NULL;
            //free(target);  <-- this doesnt work
            // else c complains that memory used after free
            return head;
        }
    }
    //if first in list
    if (is_list_empty(*prev) == 0){
        printf("first in chain\n");
        sleep(1);
        head = head->next;
        free(prev);
        return head;
    }
    //else
    printf("in the middle of chain\n");
    *prev->next = *target->next;
    printf("new list:\n");
    print_list(head);
    sleep(1);
    //free(target);  <-- this doesnt work
    return head;
}
```

console output in this state:

```
(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
prev:(0)->
target:(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
after jump target:(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
new prev:(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
in the middle of chain
new list:
(e,f)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
(e,f)->(a,b)->(x,y)->

=================================================================
==36817==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f9b91de5279 in __interceptor_malloc /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x56450617e2ea in make_list src/llist.c:11
    #2 0x56450617e7db in remove_from_list src/llist.c:66
    #3 0x56450617f16c in main src/main.c:45
    #4 0x7f9b91a1db24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f9b91de5279 in __interceptor_malloc /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x56450617e2ea in make_list src/llist.c:11
    #2 0x56450617e696 in add_to_list src/llist.c:56
    #3 0x56450617f027 in main src/main.c:35
    #4 0x7f9b91a1db24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 32 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

console output with the free's enabled:

```
(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
prev:(0)->
target:(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
after jump target:(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
new prev:(e,f)->(c,d)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
in the middle of chain
new list:
(e,f)->(a,b)->(x,y)->
=================================================================
==36962==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000050 at pc 0x5567843aacc0 bp 0x7ffc96b0e130 sp 0x7ffc96b0e120
READ of size 16 at 0x602000000050 thread T0
    #0 0x5567843aacbf in print_list src/llist.c:125
    #1 0x5567843ab194 in main src/main.c:46
    #2 0x7f415e820b24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)
    #3 0x5567843aa1fd in _start (/home/prog2/Project3/RaphDiener/pagerank+0x21fd)

0x602000000050 is located 0 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000060)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f415ebe7f19 in __interceptor_free /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:127
    #1 0x5567843aabba in remove_from_list src/llist.c:116
    #2 0x5567843ab184 in main src/main.c:45
    #3 0x7f415e820b24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f415ebe8279 in __interceptor_malloc /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x5567843aa2ea in make_list src/llist.c:11
    #2 0x5567843aa696 in add_to_list src/llist.c:56
    #3 0x5567843ab0d1 in main src/main.c:39
    #4 0x7f415e820b24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free src/llist.c:125 in print_list
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa[fd]fd fa fa 00 00
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==36962==ABORTING
```

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]

Comment: @Add What is the purpose of this silly statement node_t *prev = make_list();?!

Comment: @Add This loop     while (index > 0){
        *prev = *target;
        target = target->next;
        index--;
    } can invoke undefined behavior when the number of nodes in the list is less than the value of index.

Comment: There's no dynamic memory allocation in the code posted so where is the memory leak?

Comment: @Lundin What about make_list?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The definition is not posted. It could be a function formattning the HD for all I know.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is: free memory at the same level/module where you allocate it. So if there's a make_list function doing dynamic allocation, there needs to be a corresponding delete_list function.

Comment: @Add There is nothing to discuss. Your function definition does not make a sense. For example this if statements if (is_list_empty(*target) == 2){ looks very silly. Rewrite the function anew.

Comment: @Add The function is_list_empty should return either true (1) or false( 0 ) What does 2 mean for readers of the code?! In whole the function definition is silly. You allocating memory when it is not required. You wrote a while loop that can invoke undefined behavior and so on. Very and very silly function definition.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition is incorrect has redundant memory allocation

```
node_t *prev = make_list();
```

(if a function needs to delete something when why does it create something?!) can invoke undefined behavior

```
while (index > 0){
    *prev = *target;
    target = target->next;
    index--;
}
```

(there is no check in the loop whether target is equal to NULL) and its code is unclear

```
if (is_list_empty(*target) == 2){ //true
```

(what does the magic number 2 mean?! A reader of the code expects that the function should return either 1 (true) or 0 (false))

I will show how the function can be simply implemented.
Investigate it In any case if you want to write your own function definition nevertheless the presented function definition will useful for you.

```
int remove_from_list( node_t **head, size_t index )
{
    while ( *head && index-- )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node_t *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called at least like

```
remove_from_list( &head, index );
```